# Set readonly secifics cells of a Datatable bound on Datagrid in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable, datagrid

I have a `DataTable` filled and bound to my `DataGrid` and i want to know how to set some specifics cells readonly following the MVVM approach.

**my DataGrid :**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding oTable, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*">
```

I don't know how to do that. Should i bind a `bool` to the readonly property, or do something else when i fill the `DataTable`?

Thanks to advise ;)

**EDIT 1 :**

I use a Datatable binded to the Datagrid to be able to fill it during the runing time and to be able to have columns generated dynamically but if you have other solutions who make it possible to do that, i will be happy to try it.

**EDIT 2 :**
This is how i fill the `DataTable`.
The data i put in it are structured hierarchically (with the composite design pattern (the elements is the composite and the attributes the leaves) and i put only  elements who have some attributes. So i have an attribute `isEditable` on each leaves. In the following code it can be access with `attr.isEditable();`.

```
private void getNewData(List<ElementBaseViewModel> rootElement)
    {
        _oTable.Clear();
        foreach (var element in rootElement)
        {
            buildFromChildren(element);                      
        }
        var tempTable = _oTable;
        _oTable = null;
        RaisePropertyChanged("oTable");
        _oTable = tempTable;
        RaisePropertyChanged("oTable");        
    }

private void buildFromChildren(ElementBaseViewModel element)
    {
        if(element.Children != null)
        {
            if (isAttributeChildren(element))
            {
                DataRow oRow = _oTable.NewRow();
                foreach (var attribute in element.AttributeChildren)
                {
                    Model.Attribute attr = (Model.Attribute)attribute.Element;
                    if (!_oTable.Columns.Contains(attr.name))
                    _oTable.Columns.Add(attr.name);
                    oRow[attr.name] = attr.Value;
                }
                _oTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
            }
            foreach (var elem in element.ElementChildren)
            {
                buildFromChildren(elem);
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand the solution proposed by mm8 but i don't understand how to bind `isEditable`  to disable the editing.

Comment: I know you say cells but Is it specific cells or columns you want to make read only?

Comment: Cells. I need to make some of them read only.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to make a column read-only:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "YourColumnName")
    {
        e.Column.IsReadOnly = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** You could use a `Style` with a `DataTrigger` to disable the editing of individual rows or cells:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" ItemsSource="{Binding oTable, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="*"
                  AutoGeneratingColumn="datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="txtStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" />
                    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private void datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    var col = e.Column as DataGridTextColumn;
    if (col != null)
        col.EditingElementStyle = datagrid.Resources["txtStyle"] as Style;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that can be a good start but more precisely i need to make some cells read only.

Comment: What cells? How do you know whether a specific cell should be read-only?

Comment: The data with which i filled the Datatable have a boolean attribute named "isEditable". So i do not need to make a Column or a Row read only but more precisely the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will be very kind if you can check my edit.

Comment: It would be very kind of you to accept answer to your questions instead of modifying the question...